# how to install plugins to play media files of the following type: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) decoder?

Tags: 15.10

Videos requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) decoder

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Now it will work.

[What is ubuntu-restricted-extras?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats)